# how to apply if condition on fields of json contained in a log

Tags: logging, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I have a log which contains json, i want to apply if condition on one of the fields of json.
log format:

```
[2018-03-22T16:47:31.113] INFO {"code":200,"type": "everything looks good", "text":"Starting server at port => 5003"}  {../../app.py:14:8}
```

I am trying to apply condition based on the code, that is if code is 200 then it should add a field "status" => "success".

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "\[(?<timestamf>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601})\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:json}  %{GREEDYDATA:file}" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamf", "ISO8601" ]
    target => "timestamf"
  }     
  if [json][code] == 200 {
    mutate { 
      add_field => { 
        "Status" => "Success" 
      }
    }
  }
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `code` is not a separate field in your `grok` pattern, its just a plain-text data under `json` field which is under `message` field because you use `GREEDYDATA`.

You need to create a separate field for `code` to use it in conditional statement.

After `%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}` in your grok pattern you can add the following `{"code":%{INT:code}` right before `%{GREEDYDATA:json}` so it should read,

```
 %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} {"code":%{INT:code}%{GREEDYDATA:json}
```

From Logstash [Field Reference documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#logstash-config-field-references),

> The syntax to access a field is `[fieldname]`. If you are referring to
>   a top-level field, you can omit the `[]` and simply use `fieldname`. To
>   refer to a nested field, you specify the full path to that field:
>   `[top-level field][nested field]`.

your rest of the condition block is almost correct, but since `[message]` is your top-level field and `[code]` is its nested field now, you can access it like,

```
if [message][code] == 200 {
    mutate { 
      add_field => { 
        "Status" => "Success" 
   }
}
```